# MAAS - unable to create vlan interface on node

Tags: networking, juju, maas

I am attempting to add a vlan interface to one of my commissioned nodes. However when adding interface I receive 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fabric_id'
I have attempted this on physical interfaces, and a bond (desired interface). Both fail. Here is maas version and data.

Is this a bug? or does someone know how to fix?

```
user@us-a-maas:~$ maas admin version read
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
{"version": "2.3.0", "subversion": "6434-gd354690-0ubuntu1~16.04.1", 
 "capabilities": ["networks-management", "static-ipaddresses", "ipv6- 
deployment-ubuntu", "devices-management", "storage-deployment-ubuntu", 
"network-deployment-ubuntu", "bridging-interface-ubuntu", "bridging- 
automatic-ubuntu", "authenticate-api"]}
```

#

```
user@us-a-maas:~$ maas admin node read h6g7w8
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
{
"status": 4,
"node_type": 0,

   {
    "enabled": true,
        "name": "ens3f0",
        "children": [],
        "system_id": "h6g7w8",
        "links": [],
        "discovered": null,
        "vlan": null,
        "tags": [
            "sriov"
        ],
        "params": "",
        "mac_address": "14:02:ec:82:66:78",
        "effective_mtu": 1500,
        "id": 98,
        "type": "physical",
        "resource_uri": "/MAAS/api/2.0/nodes/h6g7w8/interfaces/98/",
        "parents": []
    },
```

#

```
    {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "tenant-bond",
        "children": [],
        "system_id": "h6g7w8",
        "links": [],
        "discovered": null,
        "vlan": null,
        "tags": [],
        "params": {
            "bond_lacp_rate": "fast",
            "bond_downdelay": 0,
            "bond_mode": "802.3ad",
            "bond_miimon": 100,
            "bond_updelay": 0,
            "bond_xmit_hash_policy": "layer3+4"
        },
################################
user@us-a-maas:~$ maas admin vlan read 1 14
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
{
    "primary_rack": "m3ppf4",
    "name": "os-tenant-net",
    "secondary_rack": null,
    "mtu": 9000,
    "fabric": "OpenStack-Nets",
    "vid": 14,
    "space": "tenant-net-api",
    "relay_vlan": null,
    "dhcp_on": true,
    "id": 5008,
    "external_dhcp": null,
    "fabric_id": 1,
    "resource_uri": "/MAAS/api/2.0/vlans/5008/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add alias or vlans to an interface, interface must be first assigned to the proper fabric.

To do so update the interface with proper fabric, untagged interface, if any, and IP Address.

Once this was completed I was able to move forward.